# mysql function does not work in react after several excution

Tags: mysql, reactjs

here is node.js code

```
var _num;
app.post("/api/get", (req, res) => {
    _num = req.body.passNum;
    console.log(_num + "insert");
    callDb();
});



var callDb = () => {
    app.get
    ("/api/get", (req, res) => {
        var sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM day" + _num;
        console.log(_num + "outcome");
        db.query(sqlSelect, (err, result) => {
            res.send(result);

        });
    });
};
```

1. What is this code? : this code get a number from frontend(react) by click url (from day1 to day3) and it passes into var _num inside backend.
   and function callDb gets the var _num, and add in to mysql query, so in conclusion, callDb calls different table from mysql(from day1 to day3).
2. what is problem? : The first few times work normally, and when clicked several times it doesn't work normally. as you see in my code, to check whether it is working properly, I added console.log (insert and outcome). as callDb inside app.post, after _num gets number from react, callDb has to be start.

so the sequence is, click day1 url->_num gets value"1" and console.log insert comes out(1 insert)->callDb SELECT day1 and console.log outcome comes out (1 outcome).

and after repeat click and go back to main page, the log is

1insert
1outcome

2insert
2outcome

3insert
3outcome

1insert
1outcome

2insert
2outcome

3insert

so from the six time, it makes problem. Only appears insert and after click, there is no log change. which means SELECT did not worked. and after refresh page, consolelog outcome gives proper outcome. so every 6click, user requires refresh.

I'm really confused because it works several times, and at some point it brakes. what is the problem and how can I fix?

Comment: Are you passing raw SQL from the client frontend to your MySQL server?

Comment: From node.js. from frontend only gets _num through axios and when node.js Select proper table, on frontend it shows the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
    app.post("/api/get", (req, res) => {
    if(req.body.passNum){//first check if the required parameter is provided
        _num = req.body.passNum; //get the parameter. You need to use 'escape string' to escape other dangerous characters which may lead to sql imjection.
        
        db.query("SELECT * FROM day" + _num, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);          
                res.end("An error occcured while reading from the database");
            } else {
                res.send(result);
            }
        });
    }else{
        res.end("required fields are not provided");
    }    
});
```

Comment: I have changed my code into your code, but on chrome it says GET http://localhost:3001/api/get 404 (Not Found).  I am pretty sure my  original code worked until getting the parameter. And there is no log in node.js terminal.